# Scrivener changes my font size

Tags: scrivener

I use Scrivener, and sometimes when I highlight a line or even just click the cursor, the font shrinks to tiny. When I check the font size on the computer, it hasn't changed (still size 12), but clearly the font on the screen is small.

How do I make this STOP! Sometimes its so small I can't read it.

Comment: If you can, take a screenshot or make a video recording of the problem and send a bug report to the developers at https://www.literatureandlatte.com/support.php#section-bugs

Comment: Zoom the page in. If that doesn't work, I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: To anyone considering voting to close: [Scrivener questions are firmly on-topic here](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/q/276/26). Please consider submitting edits if you think the question can be improved.

Comment: Please specify what operating system you are using, and Scrivener version. I believe that the Scrivener forum will be more helpful.

Comment: @NeilFein this isn't a matter if they are on topic here.  In this case, this is a software bug/glitch that should be reported to the company and or going to the support forum for scrivener seeking technical help or calling their CS deptartment.  This isn't a "how do I use this feature" this is a "I have this bug in the software".

Comment: I appreciate all the comments and suggestions.  I know see its a glitch and nit setting I am doing to make it happen. I have contacted the company and will trouble shoot with them. I apologize to anyone who felt this was not appropriate for this forum. Thanks to all who offered help and suggestions.

Comment: @sladuke Hey bro, if you ever have questions about scrivener's functions and what you can do with it (there are many cool hidden gems of tools you can use from what I have seen in this site), definitely feel free to ask.  The problem with this question is that, we would need to go through a trouble shooting process. Asking you to try this, do that, restart the PC, all that good tech support stuff which doesn't fit our format as it is a Questions and Answers site, and not particularly a forum, similar to Quora.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think this question is perfectly fine here.

Answer (score 3):

This is simply a bug, not intended behaviour, which is why nobody here can give you a definite answer about how to make it stop. If you see such a behaviour try to file a bug report on [their bug reporting site](https://www.literatureandlatte.com/bug-reporting). Be sure to include the important information, such as the version of the software you are using, the operating system, the settings you changed from the standard and step-by-step instructions on how to reproduce the behaviour. This is something where you need the help of the company.

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same problem and it drove me crazy. Sometimes half the page is small font and the other half large, but when I check the font size, everything is the same for both the enlarged and small or regular font size part of the page.

**Solution:**

- Click on the body of the page you are having issues with,
- Go to the dash click on view, then zoom.
- Zoom in or out should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the text that has text that wont change size and paste it into a word document and change the size there. Then paste it back into your scrivener document, not the most eloquent way to do this but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if you highlight the shrunken text (then immediately un-highlight it) it reverts back to the desired font size.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE John L, glad you found us.  We have a [tour] and [help] you might wish to check out.